# Email header injections

Tags: php, forms, html-email

I wanted to know if the following code will prevent email header injections in my HTML email form?

(I referenced this code from another website.)

My code is below.

```
$SpamErrorMessage = "Whoa, slooooooow doooown";
if (preg_match("/http/i", "$first")) {echo "$SpamErrorMessage"; exit();}
if (preg_match("/http/i", "$last")) {echo "$SpamErrorMessage"; exit();}
if (preg_match("/http/i", "$email")) {echo "$SpamErrorMessage"; exit();}
if (preg_match("/http/i", "$message")) {echo "$SpamErrorMessage"; exit();}


/* Email Variables */
$emailSubject = 'You have received an inquiry from your website';
$webMaster = 'info@3elementsreview.com';

/* Data Variables */
$first = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['First']));
$last = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Last']));
$email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['E-Mail']));
$message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message']));

$body = <<<EOD
<span style="color:#454545; font-weight:bold; font-size:1.6em;">$first</span><br>

<span style="color:#454545; font-weight:bold; font-size:1.6em;">$last</span><br>

<span style="color:#454545; font-weight:bold; font-size:1.6em;">$email</span><br>
<br>
<span style="color:#252525; font-size:1.4em;">$message</span><br>
EOD;
$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body,
$headers);
```

Comment: How is anyone suppose to inject your email headings if it's not a specific "headings" input field? Just validate the email and you should be fine.

Comment: @Jonast92 He is including a "From" header that has the email address passed by the form.

Comment: You could send a link to their email then have them click it to validate that they're not a spammer before sending yourself an email. I would just use your built in spam filter on your SMTP server.

Comment: @PHPglue most SMTP servers do not do outbound filtering.

Comment: I believe he's sending the mail to himself. Filter it when you get it.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I know, but I feel like he's over-thinking it.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is:

> Never, ever, ***EVER*** send an email impersonating someone else.

Ok, so they filled in the 'From' box in your form, and maybe it's a valid email addess. That doesn't mean that it technically or ethically correct to send an email *on the behalf* of that address. Doing something like that is virtually guaranteed to run afoul of SPF or DKIM checks these days and all your mail will be tossed in the bin.

What you *should* be doing is sending the email with a 'From' address that is within your own domain. It should also be a real account that can handle any bouncebacks.

Or if you want to do it anyway, you should probably try validating that your input data matches an expected format, aka 'is an email address'. There are [many regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) to do that.

Currently you code just checks if the input contains the string 'http', says "good enough", and ploughs through to sending the message.

Comment: How would I prevent the email from being sent with 'http' in any of the input fields or text area?

Comment: With the regular expressions right at the top, I guess? That's a bit beside the point. What if 'masterofhttp@domain.com' wants to submit your form?

Comment: I don't want to debate, Sammitch. With the above code I was looking for help to prevent an email header injection, as my original post states. I'm sure that is what you got out of my post through context. You pointed out the code is wrong, now I am looking for a solution, that is why I came here.

Comment: @MarlonFowler the last point in my answer remains, you should be checking to see that your form inputs match strict "good" input format definitions instead of trying to match against loosely-defined "bad" inputs. The `$from` variable is the only point of entry for header injection, so strictly checking that it is an email address and nothing else will cover your ass.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are vulnerable to attack using the provided code.

Aside from the problems outlined by @Sammitch with the 'From' address which should be fixed, I suggest scanning any input which would be included in the either message body or headers for the string "Content-Type: multipart/".

It is possible to inject all sorts of data into an outgoing message via multipart boundaries:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages